# How to find and replace text using regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I have the following text as an input.

`This is specified input. This is Specified input.`

And I want the below output.

`This is <span>specified</span> input. This is <span>Specified</span> input.`

If I do `str.replace(\specified\gi, '<span>specified</span>')` it will replace like this

`This is <span>specified</span> input. This is <span>specified</span> input.`

How can I replace this string with the matched element

Answer (score 0):

Replace with `<span>$&<span>` to insert the matched text:

```js
const str = 'This is specified input. This is Specified input.';
const result = str.replace(/specified/gi, '<span>$&<span>');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$&` to retrieve the matched string.

You also have the wrong kind of slash around your regexp.

```js
var str = "This is specified input. This is Specified input.";
console.log(str.replace(/specified/gi, '<span>$&</span>'));
```